# How can I insert value in <td> from input field with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, input, html-table, visualization

I have table with following structure:

```
<table class="table-info" border='1px' >


    <tr >
        <td class="view" style='background:red; width:100px' ></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><span class="title" style="cursor: pointer">Some title</td>
        <td title="url"><a href="#" target="_blank">088835522112</a></td>
        <td>AUDIO</td>
        <td><input class="input-text" type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
       <tr >
        <td class="view" style='background:red; width:100px' ></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><span class="title" style="cursor: pointer">Some title</td>
        <td title="url"><a href="#" target="_blank">088835522112</a></td>
        <td>AUDIO</td>
        <td><input class="input-text" type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
        <tr >
        <td class="view" style='background:red; width:100px' ></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><span class="title" style="cursor: pointer">Some title</td>
        <td title="url"><a href="#" target="_blank">088835522112</a></td>
        <td>AUDIO</td>
        <td><input class="input-text" type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>

</table>​
```

I want to visualize the value of the input field in `"td class='view'"`. How can I do this with jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/dilyan_kn/R4Dqr/

Comment: Nice one! It's a little bit offtopic but can you explain me how to make to validate inputed values that should not be higher than value of the second col (ex. 6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got you right, this should work:

```
​$(".input-text"​).on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".view").html(this.value);
})​​​​​​​​​;​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/R4Dqr/1/

Comment: It's a little bit offtopic but can someone explain me how to make to validate inputed values that should not be higher than value of the second col (ex. 6)?

Answer (score 1):

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R4Dqr/2/)

```
$(".input-text").on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find('td:first').html(this.value);
});​
```

Comment: Nice one! It's a little bit offtopic but can you explain me how to make to validate inputed values that should not be higher than value of the second col (ex. 6)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.input-text').bind('keyup', function() 
{ 
  $(this).closest("tr").css('color', 'white').find(".view").html(this.value);
});
```